# Peugeot 207, Head gasket blown?

Tags: engine, oil, diagnostics, head-gasket

4 vti coolant has a brownish color and its oily to the touch. I did an oil change about two weeks ago, I'm wondering if it could be connected, the coolant level didn't really budge.
I remember the Coolant color was blue last month. I checked the Oil cap and I've the Mayonnaise gunk.

the most confusing part of this problem is that the car is running really well, no engine light, misfires very quiet and revving good, temperature stays rock solid at 90c, not even blue smoke, or any smoke of anykind to be precise.

I'm wondering if this is a blown head casket ? I will do a compression test tomorrow.
my A/C system doesn't work neither but the car seems to heat well.

Thank you very much for any help diagnosing my car.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Done only short trips lately? A classic cause. However, get a garage to test the head gasket.

Comment: If the head gasket is leaking between the oil and coolant and not the cylinders, then you would not expect any drop in performance or any change in exhaust colour.  You would expect water and oil contamination, though.  Other things could also cause this, for example a faulty oil cooler, if the car has one.

Comment: Thank you a lot for those comments, I will check if there's an Oil cooler on this car. I was getting a Thermostat error some times ago. Could it be that a damaged thermostat is making oil leak into the coolant system ??

Comment: No but a faulty thermostat could cause overheating which could cause head or head gasket damage. But don't panic yet, there are other explanations to your problems. A compression test and cooling system pressure test should identify any problems. If they turn out good, flush the coolant system and monitor.